# JQuery - Set a div to hidden if a link has no URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I have a piece of code I want to use js or jQuery to hide a certain element - I have the following code:

`<a class="subtitle" a href="#" rco-ui-class-toggler="click">Military Families<span class="plus"></span></a>`

I want to hide the span of `plus` if the href is `#` and not an actual url, or if there is no `a href="#` on the `a` element at all.

And I have to have th code formatted for slim. Anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plain JS

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.querySelector('.plus').style.display = 'none';
});
```

or jQuery

```
$('a[href="#"]').hide();
```

You can filter more specifically as well, removing anything without a `href` attribute, or that starts with a hash

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).attr('href')  || $(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') === 0;
}).find('.plus').hide();
```

Comment: Any way to get that in coffee script?

Just to clarify, if the href IS NOT present on the a tag or the a href="#" I want to hide the span.plus element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return !this.href || this.href.indexOf('#') == this.href.length - 1;
})
.find('span.plus').hide();
```

```js
$('a').filter(function() {
    return !this.href || this.href.indexOf('#') == this.href.length - 1;
})
.find('span.plus').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="subtitle" href="#" rco-ui-class-toggler="click">Military Families<span class="plus">HIDE THIS</span></a><br>
<a class="subtitle" href="http://google.com" rco-ui-class-toggler="click">Military Families<span class="plus">DO NOT HIDE THIS</span></a><br>
<a class="subtitle" rco-ui-class-toggler="click">Military Families<span class="plus">HIDE THIS</span></a>
```

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't the last one be hidden? The reason it isn't, is because `this.href` doesn't return the attribute, but the absolute URL from the property, so it's not a very good choice for this.

Comment: The last one is hidden on my browser. What browser and version are you on?

Comment: Please give a rationale is for your explanation @adeneo.

Comment: When I commented you had `return this.href == '#'`, but `this.href` returns the absolute URL, so that wouldn't work. You've since changed it to use `indexOf` with a hack using the length because the URL is absolute. It also looked like the last anchor wouldn't be hidden because the property doesn't return `undefined` like the attribute would, but it seems it returns an empty string in some cases, which would still be falsy. It would be a lot easier to just work with the attribute instead ?